# Numbers in a Table Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Let $a_1, a_2,  \dots, a_{100}$ and $b_1, b_2, \dots, b_{100}$ be $200$ distinct real numbers. Construct a $100\times100$ table with $a_i+b_j$ written in the i-th row and j-th column. Suppose that the product of the entries of each column is $1$. Prove that the product of the entries of each row is $-1$.

I should have mentioned that I have shown it works for a $2\times2$ table, using algebra. I was wondering if it was possible to solve the main problem combinatorially.

Comment: _Presumably_, there is nothing special with $100$ here. I would, as a first attempt, try to see if this holds for $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$, and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

This follows from polynomial factorization. The first claim is saying that the polynomial
$$ f(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n (x+a_i)-1 $$
has the roots $b_1, \cdots, b_n$ (here $n$ is arbitrary). Therefore, we can write
$$ \prod_{i=1}^n (x+a_i)-1  = \prod_{j=1}^n(x-b_j). $$
Now letting $x = -a_i$ for a fixed $i$, we see that
$$ -1 = \prod_{j=1}^n (-a_i-b_j) = (-1)^n \prod_{j=1}^n (a_i+b_j).$$
Note that for $n$ even, the right hand side is exactly the product of the $i$th row, as desired.